# Debugging multicast reception

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, multicast

I'd like to debug multicast reception by the Linux kernel, because I'm not receiving any packets. Let me be more specific: I'm building a flexible userland transport mode network daemon. One of the options of running it, is using UDP sockets. One of the use cases, is to transport UDP packets that go to multicast addresses.

So I end up with UDP packets to a multicast destination, transported by a UDP packet to the same multicast destination. That's asking for trouble, I know, but I get away with it: using SO_BINDTODEVICE, I can pretty much cheat my way through the routing table and packets are sent out as I intended.

On the receiving side, I'm not so lucky. Linux does not give my receiving socket the multicast packets. It just won't see them, although tcpdump proves that they arrive at the interface. Note that unicast - using the very same sockets - is not a problem at all. I can send and receive them to my heart's content. Not so with multicast.

So I'd like to know what the Linux kernel 'thinks' in that bit between receiving the packet (which it obviously does), and giving it to my process' UDP server socket (which it doesn't do). Any thoughts?